# How to create Domino document in Outlook without lotus client install?

Tags: outlook, lotus

On Outlook 2010, i have wrote code in VB script and created the Domino document by creating Lotus Object & Session.
Please refer the below code. Its working fine when Lotus client is installed. But i need doc creation without client installation.

Whether it needs any plug-ins?

Code:

```
Dim Session As Object, NotesDB As Object, NotesDoc As Object

Set Session = CreateObject("Lotus.NotesSession") 'Getting the notes session
Session.Initialize ("password")

Set NotesDB = Session.GetDatabase("serverName", "DBPath")
If NotesDB.IsOpen Then
   MsgBox "The specified Domino database is available"
Else
   NotesDB.OpenMail
End If

Set NotesDoc = NotesDB.CreateDocument
NotesDoc.Save False, False
```

Answer (score 1):

CreateObject creates and returns a reference to a COM object. The application that provides the COM object has to be installed on that machine.

Therefore, you need Notes installed on the machine to use it's COM objects.

You can find more details in the Developerworks article [Using IBM Lotus Domino in a Microsoft .NET application](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/domino-msnet/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use DIIOP if you want to manipulate domino objects without the client installed (although I'm not sure how easy this would be with .Net). Another option would be to create an agent that does what you require and call it over http from your .Net code.

eg http://myserver/mydb.nsf/myagent?openagent&myarg1=1

Comment: Hi Jon, first i thanks to your answer. I need clarification about DIIOP concepts. You explained about how to use/implement in .Net framework. How to use DIIOP in Outlook. Again thanks in advance.

Comment: There isn't a whole lot of information online about [DIIOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIIOP), and most of the examples will be in java. You need to enable it on the domino server, then you can connect either using the stock java classes or you could try using [IIOP.net](http://iiop-net.sourceforge.net/) (no idea if this could work). If you have simple requirements, it would be much easier to do the work with an agent called via http from .Net.